# Clojure Equivalent of Javascript's Call

Tags: javascript, clojure, apply

Is there a core Clojure function that does the following?

```
(defn call [f & xs] (apply f xs))
```

In JS I'd recognize it as [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), but the closest thing I can find in Clojure is [`apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply).

I'm trying to apply an array of functions to an equal length array of operands.

```
(map call [inc dec identity] [1 1 1])
;; ===> [2 0 1]
```

I would use `apply`, except it won't work as an argument to [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) because it expects a list of arguments, rather than just arguments in place.

It can be implemented inline in a trivial way, but not with multi-arity and it feels messy.

```
(map #(%1 %2) [inc dec identity] [1 1 1])
```

It can also be done with apply and a bit of re-arranging.

```
(map apply [inc dec identity] [[1] [1] [1]])
```

But this feels even messier.